# Binding not updated when NotifyPropertyChange invoked despite ValueConverter being called

Tags: xaml, binding, uwp

Having spent a couple of days googling to resolve this, I'm hoping one of you may be able to assist.

I have a custom dependency property on a Grid control. It updates correctly when the Observable Collection is first created. However when the collection is updated (pressing the Update button in my simplified example) and NotifyPropertyChanged is called the dependency property's update method is not being called. The binding's value converter IS being called and shows the updated data (kind of implying that the binding hasn't been overwritten)

Note this is Windows Universal so some of the WPF binding trace information doesn't seem to be available.

Can anyone show some light on why the dependency property's update method is only called the first time and NOT when the NotifyPropertyChanged is invoked?

Robert

```
<Page
    x:Class="CustomBindingTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CustomBindingTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="Page_Loaded">

    <Page.Resources>
        <local:DebugConverter x:Key="debug"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Height="50" Click="Button_Click">Update</Button>
        <Grid local:GridHelpers.Cells="{Binding Path=Cells, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource debug}}" Height="500">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace CustomBindingTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Cell> Cells { get; set; }

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Cells = new ObservableCollection<Cell>();
            Cells.Add(new Cell());
            Cells.Add(new Cell());
            Cells.Add(new Cell());
            Cells.Add(new Cell());
            Cells.Add(new Cell());
            Cells.Add(new Cell());
            Cells.Add(new Cell());
            Cells.Add(new Cell());
            Cells.Add(new Cell());
            Cells.Add(new Cell());
            Cells.Add(new Cell());
            Cells.Add(new Cell());

            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Cells.Add(new Cell());
            Cells.Add(new Cell());
            Cells.Add(new Cell());
            Cells.Add(new Cell());
            Cells.Add(new Cell());
            Cells.Add(new Cell());

            NotifyPropertyChanged("Cells");
        }

        #region NotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
        #endregion

    }
}

<UserControl
    x:Class="CustomBindingTest.Cell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CustomBindingTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid Background="Green" Margin="5">

    </Grid>
</UserControl>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Text;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;

namespace CustomBindingTest
{
    public class GridHelpers
    {
        #region Cells Property

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds the Cell objectss to Grid. 
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CellsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "Cells", typeof(ObservableCollection<Cell>), typeof(GridHelpers),
                new PropertyMetadata(null, CellsChanged));

        // Get
        public static ObservableCollection<Cell> GetCells(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (ObservableCollection<Cell>)obj.GetValue(CellsProperty);
        }

        // Set
        public static void SetCells(DependencyObject obj, ObservableCollection<Cell> value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(CellsProperty, value);
        }

        // Change Event - Add the Cells
        public static void CellsChanged(
            DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(obj is Grid) || e.NewValue == null)
                return;

            Grid grid = (Grid)obj;

            List<Cell> cells = ((ObservableCollection<Cell>)e.NewValue).ToList();

            if (cells != null)
            {
                if (cells.Count() == 0)
                {
                    ShowEmpty(grid);
                }
                else
                {
                    int rowCount = grid.RowDefinitions.Count();
                    int colCount = grid.ColumnDefinitions.Count();

                    for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
                    {
                        for (int col = 0; col < colCount; col++)
                        {
                            int index = (row * colCount) + col;
                            if (index < cells.Count())
                            {
                                Cell cell = cells[index];
                                Debug.WriteLine("Row {0} Col {1} Cell {2}", row, col, index);
                                cell.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, col);
                                cell.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, row);
                                grid.Children.Add(cell);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void ShowEmpty(Grid grid)
        {
            TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
            text.Text = "[Empty Grid]";
            text.FontSize = 24.0;
            text.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            text.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            text.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
            text.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
            grid.Children.Add(text);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace CustomBindingTest
{
    class DebugConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can edit your post directly rather than making updates in comments. This will make the question more readable in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are not actually changing the Cells collection instance, you are just adding items to it.

Initially the Dependency property value is null.
In the Page_Loaded event, you are creating a new instance of an ObservableCollection() and when you set the DataContext, it updates the binding and sets the Dependency Property value to that instance.

In the Button_Click event, you are simply adding new items in the collection but that does not change the Cells instance so the Dependency property does not raise the property changed event - even if you are raising the event, the framework notices that you did not actually change the instance so it ignores the call.

I am not entirely sure what you are tying to achieve, but I do notice that you are not really using the Cells as an ObservableCollection - since you are casting it to a List<> in the Dependency ChangedCells event. As a workaround you could try to change the Cells object to be a List<> and recreate it every time you hit the update button.

Comment: Thanks Alex - greatly appreciated. I had thought NotifyPropertyChange forced the view to update even if the collection hadn't changed at all as far as the binding was concerned. This is obviously wrong! Also the code I supplied was a simplified example to illustrate the problem so the Cells object is actually used differently in the real project. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I just looked up the documentation at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx which states: _Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed._

Comment: Glad to hear it helped Robert. Don't forget to mark the post as the answer if that is what you were looking for!